# Using `Series.at` for multi index assignment ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Tags: python, pandas, series, multi-index, assign

I have a series with a multi index, I want to use [`Series.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html) to assign values. 
however when I attempt it :

```
sr = pd.Series(dtype=float,index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[]] * 2, names=('a', 'b')))
sr.at[[pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), 'DB']] = 15
```

I get an error:

```
c:\users\user\python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amax(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     28 def _amax(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     29           initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 30     return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     31 
     32 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

how to access a multi index?

Comment: Use tuple instead of list: `sr.at[(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), 'DB')] = 15`

Comment: @QuangHoang when using Tuples I get: `ValueError: Not enough indexers for scalar access (setting)!`

Comment: `at` requires both row and column indexes. You can use `loc`: `sr.loc[(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), 'DB')] = 15`.

Comment: @QuangHoang seems to work!